# Remove default locale prefix in symfony routing components

Tags: php, symfony, routes, url-routing, symfony-routing

I work **Only** with symfony routing components in personal project(without full symfony framwork). my method is: add route in `routes.yaml` file like this:

```
index:
    path:     /test
    methods: GET
    controller: 'App\Catalog\Controller\Home\IndexController::index'

register:
    path:     /test/account/register
    methods: GET
    controller: 'App\Catalog\Controller\Account\RegisterController::index'
```

my routing work fine But I need to add automatic locale prefix in uri/routing for multi language system like this:

```
mydomain/test    //for default language ie: en
mydomain/test/fr
mydomain/test/de
mydomain/test/account/register      //for default language ie:en
mydomain/test/fr/account/register
mydomain/test/de/account/register
```

How do add locale prefix in `routes.yaml` file and remove default locale prefix language ?!

Answer (score 4):

If your Application is up-to-date you can use [Internationalized routing](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-internationalized-routing) introduced in `4.1` like this

```
# config/routes/annotations.yaml
controllers:
    resource: '../../src/Controller/'
    type: annotation
    prefix:
        en: '' # don't prefix URLs for English, the default locale
        fr: '/fr'
        de: '/de'
```

Otherwise, you can reference another `routing.yml` file with prefix option like this

```
# config/routing.yml

french_route:
    resource: "french_routing.yml"
    prefix:   /fr

deutch_route:
    resource: "deutch_routing.yml"
    prefix:   /de
```

You can separate languages with files, and each one will come automatically with his own prefix

Comment: @I work Only with routing components in personal project(without full symfony framwork). your methods work with Symfony structure and full framework(ie annotations / config / ...)